# how to obfuscate jar file with dependencies by using proguard

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, proguard, obfuscation

I'm build a jar which has two dependencies(fastjson and volley) with maven in Idea IDE, now I want to obfuscate my jar but without obfuscate two dependencies jars, I've tried to do this in proguardgui, my proguard.pro content as follow:

```
-injars android_video_tv_sdk_player-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
-outjars android_video_tv_sdk_player-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-proguard.jar

-libraryjars 'C:\Users\hangl\IDE\sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Users\hangl\IDE\sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar'

-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontwarn com.alibaba.**,com.android.volley.**


-keep class com.ifeng.exception.InvalidParamsException

-keep class com.ifeng.media.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.alibaba.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keep class com.android.volley.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  PlayState {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Remove - System method calls. Remove all invocations of System
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.System {
    public static long currentTimeMillis();
    static java.lang.Class getCallerClass();
    public static int identityHashCode(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.SecurityManager getSecurityManager();
    public static java.util.Properties getProperties();
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getenv(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String mapLibraryName(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}
```

my uber jar's main package is com.ifeng.media, I want keep class under this package and obfuscate other classes in other packages, but after I process obfuscate my jar, I found most methods and fileds in obfuscated class just gone! Here's an example, I define class LogUtils.java, here's the code:

```
/**
 * Created by hangl on 2014/9/19.
 */
public class LogUtils {

    private static boolean isDebug = true;

    public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
        if (isDebug) {
            Log.d(tag, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void v(String tag, String msg) {
        if (isDebug) {
            Log.v(tag, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void i(String tag, String msg) {
        if (isDebug) {
            Log.i(tag, msg);
        }
    }
    public static void e(String tag, String msg) {
        if (isDebug) {
            Log.e(tag, msg);
        }
    }
    public static void w(String tag, String msg) {
        if (isDebug) {
            Log.w(tag, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

after obfuscate,it became class a.class, now its code became what you see now:

```
import android.util.Log;

public class a
{
  private static boolean a = true;

  public static void a(String paramString1, String paramString2)
  {
    if (a) {
      Log.d(paramString1, paramString2);
    }
  }

  public static void b(String paramString1, String paramString2)
  {
    if (a) {
      Log.e(paramString1, paramString2);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why,same situation exist in other classes, Is there something wrong with my proguard.pro file? can anyone tell me what I need to do? 
  If you have other method to reach the goal, like install plugins in maven pom.xml to obfuscate maven mudule(I've already tried this but I face same problem), please show me your way. Thanks!

Comment: Your configuration looks correct. Are you sure that `LogUtils` is inside the package `com.ifeng.media`? Note that your configuration refers to the `main` method, which is suitable for Java applications. The examples in the ProGuard documentation provide a configuration for Android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,in my sdk jar, there are four packages, com.ifeng.media(main package), com.ifeng.exception, com.ifeng.utils,com.ifeng.statistics, LogUtils under package utils,and my jar is not a runnable jar, there's no class containes main method, I will check out docs about proguard for the answer.

Comment: @Eric Lafortune  I've read your proguard main page, I realize that proguard will remove unused classes and methods, and I check my code again  find I do just use two methods in LogUtils, so what I've descript ed in my question can be explain, now I want to know can I configure some attributes to keep this unused methods? does some attributes like keepunusedmethods avaliable in proguard?

Comment: @Eric Lafortune, There's still another question, under package com.ifeng.utils there are NetUtils.java、NetUtils and LogUtils three java file, I acctually use all of them, but after obfuscate my jar, only two obfuscated classes can be found under this package, like what you say "It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes." It seems this cann't explain what I've experienced. can you tell me why? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of ProGuard is to remove classes, fields, and methods, and to rename the remaining classes, fields, and methods whenever possible. In that respect, it seems to be working fine. It is plausible that the LogUtils and NetUtils classes are removed or renamed, since they lie outside com.ifeng.media.**, which you are keeping. You can perhaps state more clearly what you expect or what kind of problems you experience with the processed code?

If you want to process the code as an Android application, you can look at the ProGuard manual > Examples > A complete Android application. Alternatively, the Android Ant plugin, the Android Gradle plugin, the Android Eclipse plugin, or the Android Maven plugin can get you a long way.

If you want to process the code as an Android library, you can look at the ProGuard manual > Examples > A typical library. Alternatively, the Android Gradle plugin may help.

Comment: thank you, afater read more about how to use proguard, I've generated obfuscated android lib, and it works well.

Comment: ， I also try to use proguard-gui to obfuscate code, except keep classes and enum, I also want to keep interfaces in my sdk, but I just found entrances for keep class\enum\RMI etc, but don't found entrance just for public interface, where it is?